# im getting this error when im running my server with docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

I am getting this error when I am running my node JS server with docker when i build it with gets build successfully but when I run this I get this error

I tried deleting the docker image and but I did not work

Comment: attach Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `dockerfile`

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:16.13.1

# Set the working directory to /home/app
WORKDIR /app

# Bundle app source
COPY package*.json ./

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm install

COPY . .
# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

CMD npm run dev
```

Comment: its not working bro im still getting the same eror

Comment: Add your `dockerfile`